# Cypher to search across all nodes and all properties in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j instance in which I have multiple types of nodes (Labels), each with their own set of properties. So, say I have:

Label "Person" with Properties ("Name","Address","Father's Name")
Label "Location" with properties ("Name","Country","City")
Label "Event" with properties ("Name","City","Country")
and so on...

Now one way is to search for a query like "xyz" when I know the specifics:

Say: match (n:Person) where n.Name="xyz" return n

My question is, is there a single 'efficient' cypher query which can do a blind search. Basically it should be able to search all Labels and all properties and give me the nodes that match. So a single query to match 'xyz' with all properties of Person, Location, Event and other Labels in my database.

I understand one way could be using an extremely long where clause, wherein I hard-code all my labels and their respective properties, but I am not looking for that. Is there a straightforward neo4j Cypher to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can do a full graph scan which of course is O(n) type thing:

```
match (n) 
with n, [x in keys(n) WHERE n[x]='xyz'] as doesMatch
where size(doesMatch) > 0
return n
```

Another - more performant but also way more complex - approach would be implementing a `TransactionEventHandler` putting all properties into an legacy index and then to query on that one.

Comment: Hi Stefan, Thanks. The query does work but as mentioned by you is extremely slow. Right now my graph is just a few million nodes and the query takes time. I understand this is not scalable. Do you suppose integrating Neo4j with Solr/Lucene might be an option. So all universal searches can be directed at Lucene as I believe it is more optimized to handle such scenarios?

Comment: We had same problem and was able to overcome using Apache Solr. Performance is quite good but needs to sync with neo4j whenever you do changes to db which is the only drawback we faced.

Comment: Upgaraded request allow search text in list properties: 
`match (n) 
with n, [x in keys(n) WHERE "text" in n[x]] as doesMatch
where size(doesMatch) > 0
return n`

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that while neo4j is good for searching things when relationships are involved, or when you can constrain the nodes searched by certain labels and properties, your kind of search is not neo4j's forte. Few databases are good for this kind of all-encompassing search.

You may want to consider adding an ElasticSearch layer on top of neo4j, as it's THE tool for any kind of rich searching in a database.

Comment: Thanks. My knowledge around ElasticSearch is rather limited, but I believe conceptually it is similar to Lucene. Also I think by default neo4j uses Lucene indexes. I just wanted to understand how integrating ElasticSearch (https://neo4j.com/developer/elastic-search/) is gonna be better than legacy lucene indexing. Or am I completely wrong in my assumptions?

Comment: My understanding is ES uses an inverted index over all fields of all documents. This is perfect for blind searches like your case, it should be blazing fast. Neo4j uses Lucene, but indexing is not full text across all nodes. You'll only see benefit where schema indexes (or unique constraints) are created on a :label(property) combination. For neo4j to support blind search across everything, you'd need to create indexes on every label/property combination, seriously bad idea, with hard manual upkeep for new properties or labels. For these expansive search requirements, use an ES layer on top.

Comment: Apparently legacy indexes in neo4j may be configured for full text searching across everything. You may want to check the manual for this, and also see if you have to do anything explicit to use the index. Schema indexes are used under-the-hood whenever possible, but I think you need to manually invoke legacy index use.

Comment: The [APOC Procedures library](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) includes support for creating a full-text index, but be aware that results back are limited to 100 at a time.

Comment: Just to amend my last comment, the limit is configurable when calling.